# Include After Effects Expressions questions in the Graphic Design forum?

Tags: discussion

I tried to post a question regarding After Effects expressions in the Graphic Design forum -  that was flagged as off topic.  I am aware that code scares many designers away, but in my experience, expressions are written in After Effects to achieve visual effects that are likely not possible by using keyframe-based animation alone.  How an expression is coded is very much a design decision.

I tagged the question with "adobe-after-effects" but was surprised that there was no expressions related tag.  Am I truly off topic with the subject of my question?  I'd appreciate hearing any opinions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Effect is video based. Not many **graphic** designers will have the knowledge or experience to help with After Effect, let alone After Effects Expression.

You would probably be better off trying the Audio-Video Stack Exchange:
https://video.stackexchange.com/

And for the record, "code" doesn't scare designers. It may be an area they don't have experience with, but there are **many** designers who code as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's about being scared off.

I'm a designer/coder leaning heavily toward the coder side of things. At the same time, I wouldn't expect to see any AE Questions on GD/SE, and AE code even less! There is a dedicated SE site for that as @Scott mentioned.

I keep my coding questions to SO, as you should keep your AE Expressions questions to AVP or whatever other site is appropriate.

If we started greying the lines between the sites, they wouldn't have such high quality questions on specific areas.

Even if everyone was 'scared' of the code, wouldn't that in itself be enough of an indication that you're probably not going to get a good answer in this community?